# sudo fails from GDM

Tags: permissions, sudo, gdm

I login as a adminx, a root-group user, in the graphics environment 18.04. Then I click on terminal, it never opens, it times-out. Then I open Terminator, and it does open. I type `sudo ls`, and it fails with:

```
sudo: unable to set runas group vector: Operation not permitted
```

Then  it asks for Admin's password, I type it, then it fails again with

```
sudo: PAM authentication: System error
sudo: unable to open audit system: Operation not permitted
```

This is my user:

```
adminx:x:1000:
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: could you edit your question please? use new lines to make the text breathe, use code formatting for the bits that were either typed into terminal or copied from the terminal. and organise. first say what you want to have (what context/software ect) and what is the happening instead, then you can develop in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like the problem mentioned and solved here:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=182861

The solution mentioned there: run the command

```
sudo grpck
```

This command verifies the integrity of /etc/group and /etc/gshadow